# Why wont this PHP script submit form data to mysql?

Tags: php, html, xhtml

This script is supposed to get the content of a text area and submit it to mysql, but it isnt can anyone see why?

```
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") 
{
$error = '';
$like = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['like_box']);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO likes (like) VALUES ($like)");

$id = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM likes WHERE like=$like");
header('Location:like.php?id='.$id.'');
}?>



<form method="post" action="post.php">
                <textarea name="like_box" id="like_box" style="border-style: none; border-color: inherit; border-width: 0; width: 458px; height: 65px" class="style11120"></textarea>

            <tr>
                <td style="height: 53px">
                <div class="style11116" style="width: 417px">
                    <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
                    </form>
```

Comment: Did you try debugging, in the post.php file, write `echo $_POST['like_box']; die();`  does it work there ?

Comment: In the script are you connecting to the database and selecting it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having some error reporting would tell you that you need ' around the `$like` and you need ` around like in the columns section, since [like is a reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html), inside the insert.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO likes (`like`) VALUES ('$like')") or trigger_error('Query Error: ' . mysql_error());
```

Should work.

---

Also you will need to enclose the like in ` for the select:

```
$id = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM likes WHERE `like`=$like") or trigger_error('Query Failed: ' . mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 2):

Your first SQL query is wrong. You have to enclose string values with quotation marks in SQL:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO likes (`like`) VALUES ('$like')");
```

The rest of your PHP part will not perform as you wish either. $id will be a resultset, not a value. You'll have to fetch the row like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM likes WHERE `like`='$like'");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$id = $row['id'];
```

Or even better, just replace the second SQL query with a call to [mysql_insert_id](http://php.net/mysql_insert_id):

```
$id = mysql_insert_id();
```

---

Still more possibilities for improvement:

- Don't forget to call `exit` after you've done a `header('Location: ...');` call, otherwise you may get unexpected results since the script will continue running.
- Add some error handling of your insert. At least check with an if statement that it succeeded.